# websocketpp: Getting exception on tls init handler

Tags: websocket

I am nusing WebSocket++/0.3.0-alpha4 in my wxwidgets application (win32). 
So far, I am able to connect the ws url ( ws://localhost:3000).
But getting prb while trying with the wss url (wss://localhost:443).
I have created a object of client as follows.

```
typedef websocketpp::clientwebsocketpp::config::asio_tls_client client;
client m_client;
```

and register the tls handler on constructor as follows,

```
m_client.set_tls_init_handler(bind(&WebSocketClient::on_tls_init, this,::_1));
```

When call comes in this handler, it throws an exception on very first line written as follows

`context_ptr ctx(new boost::asio::ssl::context(boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv1));`

While debugging, I came to know is exception is thrown from context.ipp ( Boost\asio\ssl\impl)..

```
if (handle_ == 0)
{
    boost::system::error_code ec(
    static_cast(::ERR_get_error()),
    boost::asio::error::get_ssl_category());
    boost::asio::detail::throw_error(ec, "context");
}
```

What's going wrong here. Please Help.